# Is swift/objective-c an event oriented language like javascript?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift

I have just started with iOS development. I notice that there are a lot of functions that can be written that will run when the user interacts with an object, which reminds me of java script. Is swift/objective-c event driven language?

Comment: Unclear what you asking - first of all, what you are describing is not native to javascript. It's more or less a property of DOM or additional javascript libraries (e.g. reactive programming). Only a small amount of languages have a native support for events and neither Javascript/Obj-C or Swift is one of them. However, there are libraries for all of them that are adding that functionality but it's not a functionality of the language. Most UI frameworks use event delivery too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, remember that event-driven programming can be done in any languages :) The only thing to say here is some languages can provide more convenient syntax than the others.

In Objective-C or Swift you may find it easy to do event handling with selector/block/closure/delegate